# error when multiple http request happens on the same repository with Autofac on asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A
>   DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is
>   still being configured at this point.

Although the message is clear, I have tried so many different things with no luck. If I run a single HTTP request from the front end app, all works fine. However, the error above happens when two HTTP calls run in parallel and both require the TokenRepository.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
public class TokenRepository : BaseRepository<Token>, ITokenRepository
{
    public TokenRepository(DataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
    {

    }

    public async Task<Token> GetByTokenValue(string tokenValue)
    {
    // this is where the ERROR happens
        return await this._dataContext
            .Set<Token>()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.TokenValue == tokenValue);
    }
 }
```

Startup:

```
//setup Authorization
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Global.CustomAuthorization,
                policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CustomAuthorizationRequirement()));
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler>();

        // Create the Autofac container builder.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutoFacModule());

        // Populate the services.
        builder.Populate(services);

        // Build the container.
        this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        // Create and return the service provider.
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
```

Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repositories.Repos.BaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IBaseRepository<>));
        builder.RegisterType<Repositories.Repos.HomeRepository>().As<IHomeRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repositories.Repos.ContactRepository>().As<IContactRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repositories.Repos.AccountRepository>().As<IAccountRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repositories.Repos.TokenRepository>().As<ITokenRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repositories.Repos.SanctuaryRepository>().As<ISanctuaryRepository>();


        //Services
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseService<,>)).As(typeof(IBaseService<,>));
        builder.RegisterType<HomeService>().As<IHomeService>();
        builder.RegisterType<ContactService>().As<IContactService>();
        builder.RegisterType<AccountService>().As<IAccountService>();
        builder.RegisterType<TokenService>().As<ITokenService>();
        builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>();
        builder.RegisterType<SanctuaryService>().As<ISanctuaryService>();

        //Dtos
        builder.RegisterType<HomeDto>().As<IBaseDto<HomeModel, HomeDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<ContactDto>().As<IBaseDto<ContactModel, ContactDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<AccountDto>().As<IBaseDto<Account, AccountDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<TokenDto>().As<IBaseDto<Token, TokenDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<PasswordRecoveryDto>().As<IBaseDto<PasswordRecovery, PasswordRecoveryDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<ChangePasswordDto>().As<IBaseDto<Token, TokenDto>>();
        builder.RegisterType<SanctuaryDto>().As<IBaseDto<Domain.Entities.Sanctuary, SanctuaryDto>>();

        base.Load(builder);
```

Authorization

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    private IAccountService _accountService;
    private ITokenService _tokenService;

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = (context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext).HttpContext;
        this._accountService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAccountService)) as IAccountService;
        this._tokenService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ITokenService)) as ITokenService;


        StringValues authHeader;

        httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authHeader);
    }
}
```

Ok, it seems that My CustomAuthorization is asking for services that are not registered yet(?). However if I try to register the services first, I get another error saying that it could not find the CustomAuthorization

Comment: Did you try capturing the async result into a variable, dispose the dbContext and then return the result just as a matter of test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, there is a problem with using the same DataContext across multiple requests. You should consider what is a lifetime of DataContext in your case. Probably there is a problem with using this repository in Singleton (maybe in CustomAuthorizationHandler?)

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for trying to help. I just changed the BaseRepository as a matter of test, to instantiate manually a new DataContext. public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
        protected DataContext _dataContext;

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            _dataContext = new DataContext();
        }

        public virtual async Task AddAsync(T obj)
        {
            await this._dataContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(obj);
        }
 }

Comment: I still get the same error, which leads me to think that perhaps autofact has not done its job when I call the Authorization? However in the Startup, I did try to move the Authorization registration further down with no success. Anyway, I think that this test now tells us there is nothing wrong with the service registration, just a matter of registering it before the authorization happens? How could I do that?

Comment: Hmm hang on, I have more to show. I will update the main question

Comment: @WPalombini - you have declared CustomAuthorizationHandler to be a singleton. As such, it will be created only once (as well as his properties would be injected only once. So this Service will be injected only once and I suppose it has the repository and this repository will also be injected only once)  The problem here is not with registration but with lifetime of declared objects (meaning - how often they will be created during resolving in method/httprequest/app domain lifetime) Here is more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: many thanks pal! I knew it was something simple that just couldnt figure it out! I just changed from singleton to scoped and it is now working like a charm! cheers

Comment: Now you can comment, so for the next time please post guesses and questions in comments. Answers are for definitive answers to clear problems. :)

Comment: CodeCaster - You are right:) nevertheless my guess was also The solution. This is what I call intuition;)